# Use status returned from Schtasks in While statment

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to use the following Status returned below.

```
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status         
======================================== ====================== ===============
Avl3AutomationExecutor                   N/A                    Ready
```

This is generated by running the following command:
schtasks.exe /Query /S $computer /TN \TaskX

What I want to do is the following below, if the status returns as Running the PowerShell script will wait until it the status is set back to ready for executing the scheduled task again.

```
#Computer List:
$computers = "ComputerA"


foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet)
        {
         $CheckRunning = schtasks.exe /Query /S $computer /TN \TaskX
        While ($CheckRunning Stauts = Running)
        {
        Start-Sleep 30
        }
        else
        {
        Schtasks /run /tn \TaskX /s $computer  /u Username  /p Password
         }

else
        {
        }
```

Comment: Why not configure the task to automatically restart when it stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, little bit modified from your code:

```
$computers = "ComputerA"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet)
        {
            $CheckRunning = schtasks.exe /Query /FO csv /S $computer /TN "\TaskX" | ConvertFrom-Csv
            While ($CheckRunning.Status -eq "Ready")
                {
                    Start-Sleep 30
                    $CheckRunning = schtasks.exe /Query /FO csv /S $computer /TN "\TaskX" | ConvertFrom-Csv
                }
        else
                {
                Schtasks /run /tn \TaskX /s $computer  /u Username  /p Password
                }

        }
 }
```